# How do I pass Multiple Data in a single text message using Package whatsapp_unilink

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As you all can see below code contains a button that on clicked sends the data from Cloud-Firestore as a Message on WhatsApp using the package 'whatsapp_unilink' and 'url_launcher'/

```dart
String? product;
String? qnty;

Cbutton(
    text: 'Whatsapp',
    onPressed: () async {
      snapshot.data.docs
          .forEach((value) async {
        product = value.data()['Product'];
        qnty = _controller.text;
        print(product);
        final link = WhatsAppUnilink(
          phoneNumber: '+914534534553',
          text: '- $product = $qnty \n',
        );
   
        await launch('$link');
        print('$link');
      });
    },
),
```

above code returns this

```dart
I/flutter (20941): ASHNIL SYRUP (200ML)
I/flutter (20941): OLSEPT PLUS MW GARGLE 
I/flutter (20941): https://wa.me/912342424344?text=-%20ASHNIL%20SYRUP%20(200ML)%20%3D%203%20%0A
I/flutter (20941): https://wa.me/912423423444?text=-%20OLSEPT%20PLUS%20MW%20GARGLE%20%20%3D%203%20%0A
```

meaning it generates a **message(Link)** for each of the data **separately** which is not my goal, the goal is to have **all the data in a single message(Link)** and then send it to the receiver, like this:

> https://wa.me/912342424344?text=-%20ASHNIL%20SYRUP%20(200ML)%20%3D%203%20%0A-%20OLSEPT%20PLUS%20MW%20GARGLE%20%20%3D%203%20%0A

So how can I do this?

Note that the issue has nothing related to the Phone Number, it's just a dummy number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty string. Add values to in in loop then on completion send the message.

```dart
Cbutton(
    text: 'Whatsapp',
    onPressed: () async {
     String message = "";
      snapshot.data.docs
          .forEach((value) async {
        product = value.data()['Product'];
        qnty = _controller.text;
        print(product);
        message +='- $product = $qnty \n';
      });
     final link = WhatsAppUnilink(
          phoneNumber: '+914534534553',
          text: message
        );
   
        await launch('$link');
    },
),
```